# Can I use try catch like this in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making node server, to show up all elements in specific folder.

and have to stop function when path === seekPath,

can I throw result data and catch it to show all elements?

```js
app.get('/view/:id', function(req, res){
        if (req.session.key) {
            const rawData = fs.readFileSync(__folderTree + req.params.id + ".json")
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(rawData)
            const seekPath = __storage + req.params.id + "/" + req.query.path
            console.log(seekPath)
            try {
                seekFolder(jsonData, seekPath)
            } catch (result) {
                showElements(result)
            }
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    })

function seekFolder(jsonData, seekPath) {
    jsonData.children.forEach(element => {
        if(element.type === 'directory'){
            console.log("compare " + element.path + " & " + seekPath)
            if(element.path === seekPath){
                throw(element.children)
            }
            else{
                seekFolderElements(element, seekPath)
            }
        }
    });
}

function showElements(jsonArrData) {
    jsonArrData.forEach(element => {
        if(element.type === 'directory'){
            console.log("!!"+element.name)
            showElements(element)
        }
        else{
            console.log("!!"+element.name)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Node js it's just a project, not a language or a obstacle to do some try catch whereever you want, so use it, it's just javascript code. After mentioned already that, what are the type variables of path and seekPath to compare them?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. It's a reasonable solution to the problem of `forEach()` not having anything analogous to a `break` statement.

Comment: @FernandoUrban They are just two strings combined with params & queries

Comment: could you put your example code into kind jsfiddle to debug it?

Comment: @FernandoUrban ok, https://jsfiddle.net/2kv1x6yj/ is work fine for me and code runs great in my server too.

Comment: sorry for the late, i'll check it before night and i'll feedback you and thanks for the jsfiddle